# Why does python __file__ variable returns errorneous path when used in DJango?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I was trying to retrieve the file path using python `__file__` variable under django though i am getting correct path. It's behavior is little weird. Here is my attached sample code please let me know why is the behavior so.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response  
import datetime

class WebServer():


    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def display_first_page(self, request):

        print "File Path: ", __file__
        return render_to_response('Hello')
```

I have stored this code at the given location : C:\Django_example\MySample. Ideally it should have returned something like C:\Django_example\MySample\webserver.py, but instead i am getting C:\Django_example\MySample\..\MySample\webserver.py . Can someone please point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Rupesh

Comment: BTW, which version of django are you using?

Comment: I finally managed to reproduce your output. see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a current directory path you can do something like this.

```
    import os  
    os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This will return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname(absolute path) as well as it will normalizes the path. For example, on Unix and Mac OS X systems the path /var/www/project  will work fine, but on Windows systems that is not a good path. Normalizing the path will convert forward slashes to backward slashes. Normalization also collapses redundant separators, for example the path A/foo/../B will be normalized to A/B.

Rupesh

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket. Also, can you elaborate on how this is related to your question? Have you solved your problem? This will help others provide more suitable feedback/solutions.

Comment: Thanks for catching that mistake. It is not a exact answer to my question. It is just a way of solving the problem or you can say work around by using which you will get the exact path. Why is the behavior so, is still a question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm curious too, but I can't seem to replicate the behaviour (hence the question in comments above about django version).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see, `C:\Django_example\MySample\webserver.py` and `C:\Django_example\MySample\..\MySample\webserver.py` points to the same file, so it isn't errorneous.

If you want a more succinct representation of the path, try:

```
import os
print "File Path: ", os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

#### update (an attempt to understand the output of `__file__`)

The only way I can reproduce that behaviour is if I update `sys.path`. Example:

```
[me@home]$ cd /project/django/xyz
[me@home]$ ./manage.py shell
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from app import models as M
>>> M.__file__
'/project/django/xyz/app/models.pyc'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('../')
>>> from xyz.app import models as N
>>> N.__file__
'/project/django/xyz/../xyz/app/models.pyc'
```

Since the absolute path is formed by appending the relative path to the base path, I suspect you might have a `/../` somewhere in your python path.

What do you get when you print `sys.path` from your view?

Comment: Though it is pointing to the same file but __file__ was not suppose to work like this. I mean according to python documentation it should return absolute path to the file. If you could update me on this then that would really very great of you.

Comment: @Rupesh: It is an absolute path. "Absolute" merely means that it starts from the root (in your case "C:"). It does not mean it is the shortest possible path.

Comment: @Sander: You are absolutely correct sander but my point is why __file__ variable returns path as C:\Django_example\MySample\..\MySample\webserver.py whereas it should have returned C:\Django_example\MySample\webserver.py. And it does returns the same if you try to do it in a simple python script instead of django application.

Comment: As @sander mentioned, what was returned is in fact an absolute path -- it always points to the same file no regardless of your working directory. As for why there's a redundant `path\..\path` entry, my guess is it boils down to how the module loader resolves the path. Perhaps it concatenated a root path (`C:C:\Django_example\MySample`) with a relative path (`..\MySample\webserver.py`) to obtain an absolute path.

Comment: @Rupesh can you share the simple python script you mentioned?

Comment: @Shawn: Here is my main.py file code:                               from testclass import TestClass  

def main():  
    print "File Path: ", __file__  

    instance = TestClass()  
    instance.display_path()  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()  
and Here is my testclas.py file code:                               class TestClass():
    """
        Testclass comment
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def display_path(self):
        print "File Path: ", __file__

Comment: Here is the output returned after running the main.py script. Output: File Path:  C:\Documents and Settings\rupeshc\Desktop\main.py
File Path:  C:\Documents and Settings\rupeshc\Desktop\testclass.py

Comment: I think the fact that there's a realpath method on os.path suggests this is not entirely unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Following is the output of sys.path command:                      >>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['C:\\Django_example\\MySample', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\genshi-0.6-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\django_chart_tools-0.2.1-py2.6.egg', 'C:\\IVRDemo',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python26.zip', 'C:\\Python26\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python26\\lib', 
 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python26', 
 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages','C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 
 'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: @Rupesh We'll need to see `sys.path` from within your django environment. try printing it from your view just before you print out `__file__`.

Comment: @Shawn: Above output is from inside django shell itself. I have tried printing sys.path from my above django app but it printed the same output as above.

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to tell what's going on without having a look at how your module is being loaded. Can you show how your view is assigned in urls.py?

Comment: @Shawn: Here is the code of my urls.py file                      from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import databrowse
from webserver import WebServer

server= WebServer()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^homepage/$', server.display_first_page),
    )

Comment: I don't see anything amiss. I'm sorry mate, but I can't reproduce that behaviour and I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Anyways thanks Shawn for your answer and the suggestion about possible failure causes.. :)